# Why is (my) Java 25x times faster than C++?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, optimization, visual-studio-2017

I was playing around with some FizzBuzz code in Java when i wanted to compare it to C++.

I ran the Code below in Java and essentially the same Code in C++.

**Java Eclipse IDE runtime: 11sec**

**C++ Code Blocks IDE runtime: 202sec (about 18 times slower than Java)**

**C++ Visual Studio IDE runtime: 281sec (about 25 times slower than Java)**

I have the newest version installed of all of these IDEs as far as i know.

Why is this happening? Every information i have says that C++ should run faster.

Java Code:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String []args) {

    double fizzes = 0;
    double buzzes = 0;
    double fizzbuzzes = 0;
    double normals = 0;
    double iterations = 1000000;

    for (int x = 0; x < iterations; x++) {


        int index = 0;
        String output = "";

        if (x % 3 == 0) {

            output = output + "Fizz";
            index = 1;
        }

        if (x % 5 == 0) {

            output = output + "Buzz";

            index = index + 2;
        }
        if (output == "") { //x%5!=0 && x%3!=0
            System.out.println(x);
            normals++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(output);
        }


        if (index == 3) {
            fizzbuzzes++;

        }
        else if (index == 2) {
            buzzes++;
        }
        else if (index == 1) {
            fizzes++;
        }


    }

    System.out.println("Normals " + (normals/iterations*100) + "%"); //percent
    System.out.println("Fizzes " + (fizzes/iterations*100)+ "%");
    System.out.println("Buzzes " + (buzzes/iterations*100)+ "%");
    System.out.println("FizzBuzzes " +(fizzbuzzes/iterations*100)+ "%");


}
}
```

C++ Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;


int main()
{

double fizzes = 0;
double buzzes = 0;
double fizzbuzzes = 0;
double normals = 0;
double iterations = 1000000;

for (int x = 0; x < iterations; x++) {


    int index = 0;
    string output = "";

    if (x % 3 == 0) {

        output = output + "Fizz";
        index = 1;
    }

    if (x % 5 == 0) {

        output = output + "Buzz";

        index = index + 2;
    }
    if (output == "") { //x%5!=0 && x%3!=0
        cout << x<< endl;
        normals++;
    }
    else {
        cout << (output)<< endl;
    }


    if (index == 3) {
        fizzbuzzes++;

    }
    else if (index == 2) {
        buzzes++;
    }
    else if (index == 1) {
        fizzes++;
    }


}

cout << "Normals " << (normals / iterations * 100) <<"%"<<  endl; //percentage
cout << "Fizzes " << (fizzes / iterations * 100) << "%" << endl;
cout << "Buzzes " << (buzzes / iterations * 100) << "%" << endl;
cout << "FizzBuzzes " << (fizzbuzzes / iterations * 100) << "%" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

This just gives the count of Fizz/Buzzes in percentage.

Is this just a result of my IDE configurations?

EDIT: changed the C++ code to your suggestions

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{

double fizzes = 0;
double buzzes = 0;
double fizzbuzzes = 0;
double normals = 0;
double iterations = 1000000;

for (int x = 0; x < iterations; x++) {


    int index = 0;
    std::string output = "";

    if (x % 3 == 0) {

        output = output + "Fizz";
        index = 1;
    }

    if (x % 5 == 0) {

        output = output + "Buzz";

        index = index + 2;
    }



    if (index == 3) {
        fizzbuzzes++;

    }
    else if (index == 2) {
        buzzes++;
    }
    else if (index == 1) {
        fizzes++;
    }

    if (output == "") { //x%5!=0 && x%3!=0
        //std::cout << x << "\n";
        normals++;
    }
    //else {
    //  std::cout << output << "\n";
    //}
}

std::cout << "Normals " << (normals / iterations * 100) <<"%"<<  "\n"; //percentage
std::cout << "Fizzes " << (fizzes / iterations * 100) << "%" << "\n";
std::cout << "Buzzes " << (buzzes / iterations * 100) << "%" << "\n";
std::cout << "FizzBuzzes " << (fizzbuzzes / iterations * 100) << "%" << "\n";

int z;
std::cin >> z; //so i can see the values
return 0;
}
```

Also build in Release mode and outside of the IDE it runs pretty much instantly.
Seems like printing takes alot of time.

Comment: How did you compile your C++? Did you use any optimization flags? It's pointless to discuss speed if your compiler is avoiding most optimizations and emitting stuff for debugging purposes.

Comment: Pehaps you did not build you program in Release mode, or otherwise built it without any optimization. You should also try to run your code outside your IDE - you program produces a lot of text output, and some IDEs can take a whole lot of time displaying all that output, instead of letting your program run as fast as it can. (Your C++ program takes 5 seconds to complete on my machine..)

Comment: The first step: turn that off: [sync_with_stdio](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

Comment: Mmmh somehow i have never heard of optimization flags. Seems like something i have to look into.

Comment: And instead of `endl` use `'\n'`

Comment: In both cases you print to console during your loop. I would advise building the string, then printing it at the end.

Comment: A wild guess (and this is after a rather nice lunch) is that Java is faster due to string interning.

Comment: std::endl is evil

Comment: A C++ program built without optimizations is great for debugging but performs like crap - and this is what you get by default from most compilers. Enable optimizations and it will run *much* faster but will not be as debugging friendly.

Comment: @Jive Dadson it is not *evil*. You just need to know that it outputs a newline followed by a flush of the stream. Sometimes that's exactly what you want and it is the right tool - sometimes you just want to output a newline *without* the flush and then it's the wrong tool. Just because a tool does something you don't want doesn't make it bad. That just means you used the wrong tool. That's more "incompetence on your part" than "bad tool". Don't use stuff unless you know what it does.

Comment: @JiveDadson So iostreams are the source of evil!

Comment: @bath unlikely: literals in C++ fit SBO string so don't allocate.  Result of operations in Java don't implicitly intern.  Java's lazy heap, optimized for many small allocations & not delayed cleanup, may matter tho.  But most likely, sync with stdio and endl and zero optimization in C++ would explain it.

Comment: @BeniG -- Not a good way to time a program. Here is what you should do -- 1) Just turn off the unnecessary I/O, then all of the issues with `sync_with_io` and `endl` become a moot point, since you wouldn't be using any of them.  Instead use the timer functions available in each language and output the time taken at the very end of the program.  2) Run the C++ test in release mode (optimizations enabled), not debug (non-optimized) mode.

Comment: On my system `Linux Fedore 27` `C++` is twice as fast as the `Java` version even **without** optimizations. Or any of the recommended changes (like no `std::endl`)

Comment: Now, with recommended changes and optimization it is `3` times as fast as the `Java` version.

Comment: Hick. Try witing all java output to stderr, which is normally not buffered.

Comment: A **lot** of time is spent by the output terminal displaying the text. When I redirect output to `/dev/null` then `C++` is `20` times faster than `Java`.

Comment: @Galik yeah it seems that pretty much all of the time difference comes from printing during the programm. Once i disabled that it ran pretty much instantly (in Release mode).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is quite interesting, I test this in my PC, it is the same result.

Then I try to disable the print in both java and c++ (release with -O3), the time usage is <3 seconds for both.

So the problem is cout flush every time, but java is running inside a IDE, the IDE will buffer all the output,so this should be the reason why java is faster than c++.

Then I try to run java with console, and it take much longer than running inside IDE.

This should be align with the test of redirect the c++ ouputput to /dev/null by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3807729/galik

Then I change the java code to a buffered writer, the time reduced to 5 seconds inside IDE.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{

        double fizzes = 0;
        double buzzes = 0;
        double fizzbuzzes = 0;
        double normals = 0;
        double iterations = 1000000;


        BufferedWriter sout = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new
                FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out),"ASCII"), 1024);

        for (int x = 0; x < iterations; x++) {


            int index = 0;
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            if (x % 3 == 0) {

                output.append("Fizz");
                index = 1;
            }

            if (x % 5 == 0) {

                output.append("Buzz");

                index = index + 2;
            }
            if (output.length()==0) { //x%5!=0 && x%3!=0
                sout.write(String.valueOf(x));
                sout.write("\r\n");
                normals++;
            }
            else {
                sout.write(output.toString());
                sout.write("\r\n");
            }


            if (index == 3) {
                fizzbuzzes++;

            }
            else if (index == 2) {
                buzzes++;
            }
            else if (index == 1) {
                fizzes++;
            }


        }

        System.out.println("Normals " + (normals/iterations*100) + "%"); //percent
        System.out.println("Fizzes " + (fizzes/iterations*100)+ "%");
        System.out.println("Buzzes " + (buzzes/iterations*100)+ "%");
        System.out.println("FizzBuzzes " +(fizzbuzzes/iterations*100)+ "%");


    }
}
```